# Webscraping: simplify the code using a for loop inside a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, web-scraping

I've built a code for webscraping some brazilian news pages, but i've come to realize now that maybe it is unnecessarily long. I'm trying to simplify things with a for loop, but i can't find the same results. No need for showin me a brand new code, as i'm stil learning. But if someone could just give me a hint, i'd apreciate that.

The original code:

```
#web scraping: Yahoo Finanças 
url_yf = "https://br.financas.yahoo.com/"
page_yf = requests.get(url_yf)
page_content_yf = page_yf.content
soup_yf = bs(page_content_yf, "lxml")
news_yf = soup_yf.find_all("h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"})
titles_yf = [i.text for i in news_yf]

#web scraping: Estadão 
url_est = "https://www.estadao.com.br/ultimas"
page_est = requests.get(url_est)
page_content_est = page_est.content
soup_est = bs(page_content_est, "lxml")
news_est = soup_est.find_all("section", {"class" : "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-margin"})
titles_est = [i.text for i in news_est]

#web scraping: Folha de São Paulo
url_fsp = "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/"
page_fsp = requests.get(url_fsp)
page_content_fsp = page_fsp.content
soup_fsp = bs(page_content_fsp, "html.parser")
news_fsp = soup_fsp.find_all("div", {"class" : "c-headline__content"})
titles_fsp = str([i.text for i in news_fsp]).strip('[]')
titles_fsp_clean = re.sub(r'\\n', ' ', titles_fsp)

#web scraping: Valor Econômico
url_ve = "https://valor.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/"
page_ve = requests.get(url_ve)
page_content_ve = page_ve.content
soup_ve = bs(page_content_ve, "lxml")
news_ve = soup_ve.find_all("div", {"class" : "feed-post-body-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover"})
titles_ve = [i.text for i in news_ve]

#web scraping: InfoMoney
url_im = "https://www.infomoney.com.br/ultimas-noticias/"
page_im = requests.get(url_im)
page_content_im = page_im.content
soup_im = bs(page_content_im, "lxml")
news_im = soup_im.find_all("span", {"class" : "hl-title hl-title-2"})
titles_im = [i.text for i in news_im]

#cleaning titles
list_of_titles = [titles_yf, titles_est, titles_fsp_clean, titles_ve, titles_im]
titles = [title for title in list_of_titles for title in title]
```

The one i'm working on now:

```
classes = ["h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"}, "section", {"class" : "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-margin"}, "div", {"class" : "c-headline__content"}, "div", {"class" : "feed-post-body-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover"}, "span", {"class" : "hl-title hl-title-2"}]

url = {"https://br.financas.yahoo.com/": classes[0], "https://www.estadao.com.br/ultimas": classes[1], "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/": classes[2], "https://valor.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/": classes[3], "https://www.infomoney.com.br/ultimas-noticias/": classes[4]}

for (key, value) in url.items():
    page = requests.get(key)
    page_content = page.content
    soup = bs(page_content, "html.parser")
    news = soup.find_all(value)
    titles = [i.text for i in news]

cleaning = str(titles).strip('[]')
cleaning2 = re.sub(r'\\n', ' ', cleaning)
```

The idea i have is to try to loop inside the dictionary (i had to built a list of classes cause i was having trouble with the quotation marks inside the dicionary) to use the exact value relative to the url. I'm quite a noob in python yet, but this does seem possible for me. Unfortunatily, i can't find the same results.

Comment: you could keep it as sub-lists  `[ ["h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"}], [...], [...] ]` or even directly `url = {"https://br.financas.yahoo.com/": ["h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"}], ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use sub lists `["h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"}]` in list `classes` or directly in `url`

```
url = {
   "https://br.financas.yahoo.com/": ["h3", {"class" : "Mb(5px)"}], 
   "https://www.estadao.com.br/ultimas": ["section", {"class" : "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-margin"}], 
   "https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/": ["div", {"class" : "c-headline__content"}], 
   "https://valor.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/": ["div", {"class" : "feed-post-body-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover"}], 
   "https://www.infomoney.com.br/ultimas-noticias/": ["span", {"class" : "hl-title hl-title-2"}],
}
```

and then you can use `value[0], value[1]`

```
 news = soup.find_all(value[0], value[1])
```

or even using `*` to unpacak `value` as arguments for `find_all()`

```
 news = soup.find_all(*value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried after "titles = [i.text for i in news]" another for loop: "for i in titles: news_list.append(i)" to store the titles somewhere. I think i got the same results

Comment: instead of `for i in titles: news_list.append(i)` you can do `news_list = titles.copy()` to duplicate data. It works if you have numbers or strings in list. For more complex structures it would be better to use `import copy` and `new_list = copy.deepcopy(titles)`

Comment: the problem here is that it seems the copy command only stores the last url i use in the dictionary. With the append command i get the data from all the url listed in the dictionary

Comment: `copy()`  should copy all items from `titles` - But I don't know how you use it. Maybe it needs `deepcopy()`. BTW: you can also try `news_list = list(titles)` or `news_list = titles[:]`- it also copy all elements .

Comment: Nice! Thank, bro. Do u know something about cleaning the data from webscraping? Cause one of these websites ("https://valor.globo.com/ultimas-noticias/") is giving me a headache... The data is too dirty, no matter the div and class i take

Comment: sometimes you may need more complex code to get data - ie use `find_all() to get all articles, next `for`-loop to work with every article separatelly and use another `find_all()` or many difference `find()` to get different elements from single article. For clearing I use standars string functions `.strip()`, `.slice()`, `.replace()`, slicing `[star:end]` and eventually BS function `.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")`

Comment: BTW: `find()`,`find_all()` can use not only tags, ids, classes but other attributes which you can find in tag - ie. `data-type=`. You can use `text=` to search by text displayed on page. You can even use `regex`. BS can use also CSS selector instead of `find()/find_all()` or functions like `find_next_sibling()`. It can't only use `xpath`. It is good to read all in [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)